# How to add,set and get Header in request of HttpClient?

Tags: java, http, servlets, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my application I need to set the header in the request and I need to print the header value in the console...
So please give an example to do this the HttpClient or edit this in my code...

My Code is ,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class SimpleHttpPut { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://http://localhost:8089/CustomerChatSwing/JoinAction");
    try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId",
      "123456789"));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In case if you want to set specific headers for all requests, then you can set them on CLIENT, not request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707676/how-to-set-the-default-header-for-all-requests-in-apache-http-client

Answer (score 37):

You can use HttpPost， there are methods to add Header to the Request.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://localhost";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

httpPost.addHeader("header-name" , "header-value");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated

Comment: CloseableHttpClient is being used now.

Answer (score 2):

On apache page: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

You have something like this:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http").setHost("www.google.com").setPath("/search")
    .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
    .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
    .setParameter("aq", "f")
    .setParameter("oq", "");
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test-drive this code exactly as is using the public GitHub API (don't go over the request limit):

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();

        // (1) Use the new Builder API (from v4.3)
        HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
                .setUri("https://api.github.com")
                // (2) Use the included enum
                .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                // (3) Or your own
                .setHeader("Your own very special header", "value")
                .build();

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        // (4) How to read all headers with Java8
        List<Header> httpHeaders = Arrays.asList(response.getAllHeaders());
        httpHeaders.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        // close client and response
    }
}
```