# How to set the default header for all requests in apache http client?

Tags: java, httpclient

For example the default user agent could be set like:
`client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, someName);`
But how to set the "Accept" header?

Comment: Did you mean in the code level or in Apache configuration ? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html

Comment: I meant the httpclient library, not Apache server.

Answer (score 25):

HttpClient 4.3 now allows configuring a collection of default headers on the client itself:

```
Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
List<Header> headers = Lists.newArrayList(header);
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(SAMPLE_URL).build();
client.execute(request);
```

Now, all requests executed by that client will be send with the default headers. 
Hope that helps.